# running an odoo project in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, odoo

getting my feet wet with PyCharm

I have a project, it's an Odoo 14 module

PyCharm has indexed my project and it indicates errors, warnings and misspellings, ok

Now I'd like to run my Odoo in order to see what my project does

I'm assuming I should do that through some button in the GUI but I can't find it

But I see a terminal embedded in PyCharm with my virtuaelìnv activated in it

Am I supposed to run Odoo on the command line as I did when not using PyCharm ?

WHat if I want to debug something

How will the debugger attach my thing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open the Run/Debug configurations menu
2. Click on the `+` icon (top right)
3. Click on the menu item called `Python`
4. In the `Script path` entry enter the path toward your `odoo-bin` script
5. In the `Parameters` entry enter the command line options like `--dev`
6. Click on `OK`
7. Run the run configuration you just created.